# Display Associated Properties in Entity Framework

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I have a database that has tables called Visit, Consultation_fee, Lab_Test and Patient. The definition of the tables is:

`Visit` table:

- `VisitID` - integer, primary key
- `PatID` - integer
- `DateVisit` - Date

`Consultation_Fee` table:

- `ConsultID` - integer, primary Key
- `VisitID` - integer (references `VisitID` column of the `Visit` table)
- `PatID` - integer (references `PatID` in the `Patient` table)
- `Fees` - money

`Patient` table:

- `PatID` - integer, primary key
- other columns...

`Lab_Test` table:

- primary key integer
- `VisitID` references the `Visit` table
- `PatID` references the `Patient` table

My problem is that I want to run a query that gets the amount paid by a patient where the visitID and PatID corresponds to a particular value. I am using Entity Framework and Visual Studio 2012.

This is what i want to do (a sample query):

```
 Dim PatMoney=from pat in context.Visits where VisitID=a value and patID=another value
 select new with{.fees_Paid=pat.Consultation_Fees.Fee,
                 .Name=pat.Patient.Firstname}
```

However, when I do `pat.Consultation_Fees` Visual Studio does not display the other properties in Intellisense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pat.Consultation_Fees` is a *collection* of `Consultation_Fee` objects, not a `Consultation_Fee` object itself. That's why Intellisense doesn't offer any properties of the entity. Because you apparently want to build a *sum* over all the fees you can use the LINQ extension method `Sum`:

```
.fees_Paid = pat.Consultation_Fees.Sum(Function(cf) cf.Fee)
```

Comment: Thanks alot i now understand it better thanks to you. God bless you.